# Iterate Form with queryselectorall to put input value into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I Have an html page and function is JS

I noticed that myForms is a NodeList with two elements, form is 0 or 1, How do I retrieve the input values for each form?
I also tried with

```
var query = '' + myForms[form].id + ' :input');
var $inputs = $(query);
```

But at the console level I have an error -> Uncaught TypeError: $inputs[0].val is not a function

```js
function next() {

var arrayOutput = new Array();
var myForms = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="form-"]');

   

myForms.forEach(form=>{
  var query = '#' + form.id + ' :input';
      var $inputs = $(query);
  var single = {};
  single.name = $inputs[0].val();
  single.yes = $inputs[1].val();
  single.no = $inputs[2].val();
  arrayOutput.push(single);
});

}
```

```html
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
   <div id="34">
          <form id="form-34" method="post">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="container">
                <label> Model
                  <span>
                    <input type="text", id="name" name="name"/>
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="checkbox", id="yes" name="yes"/>
              <input type="checkbox", id="no" name="no"/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
<div id="35">
          <form id="form-35" method="post">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="container">
                <label> Model
                  <span>
                    <input type="text", id="name" name="name"/>
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="checkbox", id="yes" name="yes"/>
              <input type="checkbox", id="no" name="no"/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    <button class="icon" onclick=next()>Next</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use that last code snippet?  If it's inside the `forEach()` callback, don't you just want `form.id`?  If it's outside that callback, what is `form`?  Have you tried reading the error message you're getting?  What does it tell you?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates your attempt and the problem you've encountered?

Comment: *But at the console level I have an error* - what's the error?   Your query at the end is missing `#`.

Comment: Note that there are already multiple tried-and-tested methods to get values from "inputs" in a form, in [tag:jquery] you could use: `$("form").serialize();`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/02ybws8p/

Comment: Please click [edit] and update the snippet I made you with relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the forms on the page using `document.forms`. This returns a HTMLCollection that can be turned into an array using the [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

And then you can use the [FormData constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to get all the data in the form.

```js
function next() {
  let array = [...document.forms].map(form => {
    let data = new FormData(form);
    let obj = {};
    [...data.entries()].forEach(entry => obj[entry[0]] = entry[1]);
    return obj;
  });
  console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
  <div id="34">
    <form id="form-34" method="post">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="container">
          <label> Model
                  <span>
                    <input type="text", id="name" name="name"/>
                  </span>
                </label>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="yes" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="no" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="35">
    <form id="form-35" method="post">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="container">
          <label> Model
                  <span>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
                  </span>
                </label>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="yes" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="no" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button class="icon" onclick=next()>Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: $inputs[0].val is not a function

Is because this returns a plain DOM element, not a jQuery object:

```
$inputs[0]
```

Though you can create a jQuery object from it:

```
$($inputs[0])
```

Or, alternatively, don't use jQuery's `.val()` and just get the `.value` from the DOM element.

For example:

```js
function next() {
  var arrayOutput = new Array();
  var myForms = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="form-"]');

  myForms.forEach(form => {
    var query = '#' + form.id + ' :input';
    var $inputs = $(query);
    var single = {};
    single.name = $inputs[0].value;
    single.yes = $inputs[1].value;
    single.no = $inputs[2].value;
    arrayOutput.push(single);
  });

  console.log(arrayOutput);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="34">
    <form id="form-34" method="post">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="container">
          <label>
             Model
             <span>
               <input type="text", id="name" name="name"/>
             </span>
           </label>
         </div>
         <input type="checkbox", id="yes" name="yes"/>
         <input type="checkbox", id="no" name="no"/>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
   <div id="35">
     <form id="form-35" method="post">
       <div class="col-xs-3">
         <div class="container">
           <label>
             Model
             <span>
               <input type="text", id="name" name="name"/>
             </span>
           </label>
         </div>
         <input type="checkbox", id="yes" name="yes"/>
         <input type="checkbox", id="no" name="no"/>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
   <button class="icon" onclick=next()>Next</button>
 </div>
```